# Sabre PQ Record number not valid

Tags: sabre

I am getting the following response when performing a two passenger air booking in CERT:

SabreCommandLLSRQ: ÂPQ RECORD NUMBER NOT VALIDÂ

Single passenger request work as expected but if I have multiple passengers it fails.

Two Passenger request:

```
<ns2:PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns:ns2 = "http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_4" xmlns:ns3 = "http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" haltOnError = "true" ignoreOnError = "false"
version = "3.4.0">
<ns2:PostProcessing>
  <ns2:RedisplayReservation />
  <ns2:EndTransactionRQ>
    <ns2:EndTransaction Ind = "true">
      <ns2:Email Ind = "true" />
    </ns2:EndTransaction>
    <ns2:Source ReceivedFrom = "House of Rock" />
  </ns2:EndTransactionRQ>
</ns2:PostProcessing>
<ns2:PriceQuoteInfo>
  <ns2:Link nameNumber = "1.1" record = "1" />
  <ns2:Link nameNumber = "2.1" record = "2" />
</ns2:PriceQuoteInfo>
<ns2:SpecialReqDetails>
  <ns2:AddRemarkRQ>
    <ns2:RemarkInfo>
      <ns2:FOP_Remark>
        <ns2:CC_Info>
          <ns2:PaymentCard Code = "VI" ExpireDate = "2024-04" Number = "4111111111111111" />
        </ns2:CC_Info>
      </ns2:FOP_Remark>
      <ns2:Remark Type = "General">
        <ns2:Text>TEST GENERAL REMARK 1</ns2:Text>
      </ns2:Remark>
      <ns2:Remark Type = "Hidden">
        <ns2:Text>TEST HIDDEN REMARK</ns2:Text>
      </ns2:Remark>
      <ns2:Remark Type = "Historical">
        <ns2:Text>TEST HISTORICAL REMARK</ns2:Text>
      </ns2:Remark>
    </ns2:RemarkInfo>
  </ns2:AddRemarkRQ>
</ns2:SpecialReqDetails>
<ns2:TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
  <ns2:AgencyInfo>
    <ns2:Address>
      <ns2:AddressLine>House of Rock</ns2:AddressLine>
      <ns2:CityName>Santa Monica</ns2:CityName>
      <ns2:CountryCode>US</ns2:CountryCode>
      <ns2:PostalCode>90210</ns2:PostalCode>
      <ns2:StateCountyProv StateCode = "CA" />
      <ns2:StreetNmbr>1 Lincoln Blvd</ns2:StreetNmbr>
    </ns2:Address>
    <ns2:Ticketing TicketType = "7T-A" />
  </ns2:AgencyInfo>
  <ns2:CustomerInfo>
    <ns2:ContactNumbers>
      <ns2:ContactNumber NameNumber = "1.1" Phone = "7802352706" PhoneUseType = "H" />
      <ns2:ContactNumber NameNumber = "2.1" Phone = "7802352706" PhoneUseType = "H" />
    </ns2:ContactNumbers>
    <ns2:Email Address = "chris@ctrlspace.com" NameNumber = "1.1" />
    <ns2:PersonName NameNumber = "1.1">
      <ns2:GivenName>Chris</ns2:GivenName>
      <ns2:Surname>Huisman</ns2:Surname>
    </ns2:PersonName>
    <ns2:PersonName NameNumber = "2.1">
      <ns2:GivenName>karen</ns2:GivenName>
      <ns2:Surname>Huisman</ns2:Surname>
    </ns2:PersonName>
  </ns2:CustomerInfo>
</ns2:TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
```

</ns2:PassengerDetailsRQ>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer price quote created for each **passenger type** in the PriceQuoteInfo.
In case you try to book for two adults, you have to refer the same price record number for both.

Basically, you refer the `TravelItineraryReadRS/PricedItinerary` record from the previous pricing response.

So your `PriceQuoteInfo` should look something like this:

```
<ns2:PriceQuoteInfo>
  <ns2:Link nameNumber = "1.1" record = "1" />
  <ns2:Link nameNumber = "2.1" record = "1" />
</ns2:PriceQuoteInfo>
```